# Php: is there any instrumentation api for PHP like javaagent for java to detect loaded source files?

Tags: php, instrumentation

I want to do some instrumentation operation for php applications.

In java, There is the javaagent that offers the necessary hooks to do the work, But for php I don't have much experience and I don't know if it possible doable.

My goal is to detect every source file that is loaded and trying to grab it's dependencies ?

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance,

PS: I have a little knowledge for PHP and it's underlying platform so excuse me if I missed something.

Comment: are you talking about `autoloading`? http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: Yes, but without modyfing the existing code. example when launching I should add some option that before give me some hooks when loading a php file